# Creating json object in javascript and sending it to servlet for getting response

Tags: javascript, java, angularjs, servlets

I am creating json object to save data and then sending it to the servlet. But when I try to retrieve the object and display its contents in java servlet, I am not getting any response from server. Even though a simple `System.out.println()` message on browser.

```
    angular.module('TestApp').controller('PostController',
        function($scope, $rootScope, $http) {
        $scope.retriveDataAndConvertToJson = function() {
        var collectionJsonData = new Array();
        for (var i = 0; i < rowID.length; i++) {
          collectionJsonData.push({
            "payment_term": document.getElementById("textfield1" + rowID[i])
            .getAttribute("value"),
            "payment": document.getElementById("textfield2" + rowID[i])
            .getAttribute("value"),
            "party": document.getElementById("textfield3" + rowID[i])
            .getAttribute("value"),
            "amount": document.getElementById("textfield4" + rowID[i])
            .getAttribute("value")
          });

        console.log(collectionJsonData[i].payment_term);
        console.log(collectionJsonData[i].payment);
        console.log(collectionJsonData[i].party);
        console.log(collectionJsonData[i].amount);
        console.log("==========================");
      } //End of For loop

      var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
      var url = "http://" + document.location.host + "/SivaTask/processInfo";
      console.log("The url is " + url);
      xhr.open("POST", url, true);
      xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200) {
          document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML =
            this.responseText;
        }
      };
      var data = JSON.stringify(collectionJsonData);
      xhr.send(data);
    }
  });
```

**`Servlet`**

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
    String contextName = req.getRequestURI();
    String url = contextName.substring(contextName.indexOf('/', 2) + 1);
    System.out.println(url);
    String jsonData = "";
    resp.setContentType("text/plain");
    System.out.println("hello world");
    PrintWriter out = resp.getWriter();
    out.write("The information is : ");
    System.out.println("hello world2");
}
```

Comment: firstly, since you are using angularjs, use `$http` service for sending / receiving the data. Try `$http.post(url, data).then((response) => {$scope.demo = response.data;})`

Comment: Its working for Json Array object

Comment: @AshishPanda what do you want to achieve? Your post is quite unclear. Do you want to send something in the HTTP response? Do you want to print the input data? If yes, where? `System.out.println` does not print anything in the response but in the standard output of the JVM.